# Why are there two windows displayed?

Tags: python, tkinter

When the below code is run there's an additional, empty window appears. Why does that happen, and how can it be fixed?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Deneme(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.smartGui()

def smartGui(self):
    tk.Label(self, text="Name").grid(row=0,column=0)
    tk.Entry(self).grid(row=0,column=1, columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(self, text="Surname").grid(row=1,column=0)
    tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(self, text="City").grid(row=0,column=4)
    tk.Entry(self).grid(row=0,column=5, columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(self, text="Explain").grid(row=3, column=0)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Deneme()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to replace:

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Deneme()
    root.mainloop()
```

with:

```
def main():
    app = Deneme()
    app.mainloop()
```

There are two windows displayed, as there are *two* instances of `Tk`, `root`  and `app`. `app` is an instance of `Tk` as well, as `Deneme` inherits from `Tk`.

**Note:** [It's not suggested to have multiple instances of `Tk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48045401/7032856). If you'd want multiple windows, later on, you should use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk`.

---

Additionally, you could simply inherit `Deneme` from `Frame` instead of `Tk` but you'd want to configure it a bit more for it to allow you to assign its parent as `root`. Then create its instance like  `app = Deneme(root)`.