# Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

Consider below example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("root")

other_window = tk.Tk()
other_window.title("other_window")

root.mainloop()
```

and also see below example that creates instances of `Tk` back-to-back instead of at once, so there's *exactly one* instance of `Tk` at any given time:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_window(window_to_be_closed=None):
    if window_to_be_closed:
        window_to_be_closed.destroy()
    window = tk.Tk()
    tk.Button(window, text="Quit", command=lambda arg=window : create_window(arg)).pack()
    window.mainloop()

create_window()
```

- Why is it considered bad to have multiple instances of `Tk`?
- Is the second snippet considered a bit better, or does it suffer from
  the same conditions the first code does?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Why is it considered bad to have multiple instances of `Tk`?

Tkinter is just a python wrapper around an embedded Tcl interpreter that imports the Tk library. When you create a root window, you create an instance of a Tcl interpreter.

Each Tcl interpreter is an isolated sandbox. An object in one sandbox cannot interact with objects in another. The most common manifestation of that is that a `StringVar` created in one interpreter is not visible in another. The same goes for widgets -- you can't create widgets in one interpreter that has as a parent widget in another interpreter. Images are a third case: images created in one cannot be used in another.

From a technical standpoint, there's no reason why you can't have two instances of `Tk` at the same time. The recommendation against it is because there's rarely an actual need to have two or more distinct Tcl interpreters, and it causes problems that are hard for beginners to grasp.

> Is the second snippet considered a bit better, or does it suffer from the same conditions the first code does?

It's impossible to say whether the second example in the question is better or not without knowing what you're trying to achieve. It probably is not any better since, again, there's rarely ever a time when you actually need two instances.

The best solution 99.9% of the time is to create exactly one instance of `Tk` that you use for the life of your program. If you need a second or subsequent window, create instances of `Toplevel`. Quite simply, that is how tkinter and the underlying Tcl/Tk interpreter was designed to be used.

Comment: If you're going to have multiple instances of `Tk` about, they should probably be placed in separate threads so that they get their own event handling loops. It's technically possible to meld the underlying widgets from those threads into a single view, but that's a _very_ advanced technique and I don't know if it actually exposed at all within Tkinter. Frankly, keeping all GUI activity within a single thread is much simpler in practice.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, careless click, now my vote is locked.

Comment: For the curios people on how to use the advanced technique of meld the widgets together: see [`toplevel -use`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/toplevel.htm#M13) and [`toplevel -container`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/toplevel.htm#M9).

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with the `tkinter` community discouraging the use of multiple `tk.Tk` windows. You can have multiple `tk.Tk` windows. Using multiple instances of `tk.Tk` is the only way to create windows that are truly independent of each other. The only mistake most people make when creating multiple `tk.Tk` windows is that they forget to pass in `master=...` when creating `PhotoImage`s/`StringVar`s/`IntVar`s/...

For example look at this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Tk()

variable = tk.StringVar() # Add `master=root2` to fix the problem
entry = tk.Entry(root2, textvariable=variable)
entry.bind("<Return>", lambda e: print(repr(variable.get())))
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The code above doesn't work. If you add `master=root2` to the `tk.StringVar()`, then it will work perfectly fine. This is because `tkinter` stores the first instance of `tk.Tk()` in `tk._default_root`. Then if you don't pass in `master=...`, it will assume that you wanted the window in `tk._default_root`.

---

Another thing people get wrong is how many times should `.mainloop()` be called. It handles events from all `tk.Tk` windows that are alive so you only need one `.mainloop()`.

For folks who disagree, I'd be interested in an example of where an actual problem is caused by the multiple `tk.Tk` windows.

Answer (score 5):

The best reference I've found so far is the [Application Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20200724053512id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-application-windows.htm) section of the [tkinterbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20200715112618id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/):

> In the simple examples we’ve used this far, there’s only one window on the screen; the root window. This is automatically created when you call the **Tk** constructor

and

> If you need to create additional windows, you can use the **Toplevel** widget. It simply creates a new window on the screen, a window that looks and behaves pretty much like the original root window

My take on it is that a `Tk` instance creates a `Toplevel` widget, plus things like the `mainloop`, of which there should be only one.

Answer (score 0):

`Tk()` initializes the hidden tcl interpreter so that the code can run, as Tkinter is just a wrapper around tcl/tk. It also automatically creates a new window. `Toplevel()` just creates a new window, and wont work if `Tk()` hasn't been instantiated, as it requires the tcl interpreter that `Tk()` initializes. You cannot create any Tkinter widgets without instantiating `Tk()`, and Toplevel is merely a widget. In the question, you use `Tk()` to create a second window. You should instead create another file, because initializing the tcl interpreter multiple times can get confusing, as @Bryan Oakley explains so well. Then you should do:

`from os import startfile
startfile(nameOfTheOtherFile)`

, because, as `Toplevel()` is just a widget, it closes when the `Tk()` window is closed. Having the other window in a separate file makes it less confusing.

Comment: [`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) is Windows OS specific, so your solution is not generic. Also, if the other file is Python script, it might not work right if you have more than one version of the interpreter installed.